# dropbox preference not saving ("Start Dropbox on System start-up" 19.10 (xfce)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, dropbox

I just installed Dropbox by following the tutorial on their website (https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux)

The installation went OK. The command window stayed open and stuck running (not sure if this is normal?). My dropbox synced without issue.
I have the dropbox icon which appeared in the panel. Right click, preferences, then  I tick the box "Start Dropbox on System start-up". Click Apply, then OK.

Then I closed the command window, which removed the dropbox icon, so I guess I killed the process doing so? We must have a command window running to keep dropbox running? I shut down the computer, start again and dropbox doesn't launch.

I start dropbox with ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd, it starts ok.

Then when I open back the preferences, the box is unticked. Tried to do it again, it doesn't work. Everytime I open the preferences the box is unticked.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10, on top of which I installed Xubuntu-Desktop, so I'm running on xubuntu here now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to remove the Dropbox and install it again from special [Ubuntu wrapper package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=dropbox%20thunar) with

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install thunar-dropbox-plugin
```

and then enjoy its autostart and integration to Thunar file-manager.